# I want to plot 3Dhistogram from my data?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, probability-or-statistics, histograms, smoothing

I have the data file like this:

> {{16.3009, 5454}, {16.2118, 5463}, {15.8156, 5414}, {15.9585, 5515},
>   {16.2253, 5459}, {16.284, 5419}, {15.6112, 5389}, {15.7221, 5403},
>   {15.509, 5445}, {15.6993, 5401}, {15.961, 5400}, {16.6001, 5379},
>   {16.3766, 5411}, {16.4999, 5437}, {16.3784, 5483}, {16.9554, 5510},
>   {16.9463, 5482}, {17.2453, 5455}, {17.0854, 5476}, {16.9786, 5407},
>   {17.2081, 5425}, {17.4898, 5428}, {17.1521, 5457}, {17.8233, 5382},
>   {17.726, 5448}, {17.7837, 5400}, {17.5088, 5398}, {17.8232, 5454},
>   {18.4418, 5385}}

and I need to find the histogram density (probability) for my data and then get the -LOG from it and then plot the 3D plot from it? I tried too many ways but I could not figure it out, How? I can get the 3D graph from Histogram3D, but when I try to use the SmoothHistogram3D with the ScalingFunctions -> {"None", "None", "-Log"}, I got this error massage "Message text not found -- ({None,None,-Log}"

[image]

Comment: Where is your third dimension?

Comment: The third dimension would be the probability of distribution of {x,y} in the x-y surface. I need to get -LOG from this probability.

Comment: Could you post a slightly larger dataset, $n\approx 20$?

Comment: {{16.3009, 5454}, {16.2118, 5463}, {15.8156, 5414}, {15.9585, 
  5515}, {16.2253, 5459}, {16.284, 5419}, {15.6112, 5389}, {15.7221, 
  5403}, {15.509, 5445}, {15.6993, 5401}, {15.961, 5400}, {16.6001, 
  5379}, {16.3766, 5411}, {16.4999, 5437}, {16.3784, 5483}, {16.9554, 
  5510}, {16.9463, 5482}, {17.2453, 5455}, {17.0854, 5476}, {16.9786, 
  5407}, {17.2081, 5425}, {17.4898, 5428}, {17.1521, 5457}, {17.8233, 
  5382}, {17.726, 5448}, {17.7837, 5400}, {17.5088, 5398}, {17.8232, 
  5454}, {18.4418, 5385}}

Comment: So what code did you use to acquire that plot you added?

Comment: ROGF = Import["RoGf-B4MS.dat", "Table"];
NCF = Import["numcontacts-folded.dat", "Table"];
ROGF = Map[#[[2]] &, ROGF];
NCF = Map[#[[2]] &, NCF];
togather = Table[{ROGF[[i]], NCF[[i]]}, {i, 1, Length[ROGF]}];
distr = SmoothKernelDistribution[togather];

Energy1 = 
 Histogram3D[togather, Automatic, 
  ScalingFunctions -> {-Log[#] &, -Log[#] &, -Log[#] &}]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, that's already the log of the data then right?

Comment: yes, it is but I need the smooth plot of it which. I can not get the  result from SmoothHistogram3D, command.

Comment: `SmoothHistogram3D[yourdata]` works fine for me. Show what you actually tried and explain whats not right about the result.  ( *edit the question* with any clarifying info )

Comment: I can get the 3D graph from Histogram3D, but when I try to use the SmoothHistogram3D with the ScalingFunctions -> {"None", "None", "-Log"}, I got this error message "Message text not found -- ({None,None,-Log}"  (Thank you for your help)

Comment: *again* please *edit the question*.  Click the "edit" button under the key word tags.  don't post code and such into comments.  I don't think `"-Log"` is a permissible scaling function, at least its not documented.

Answer (score 3):

```
data = {{16.3009, 5454}, {16.2118, 5463}, {15.8156, 5414}, {15.9585, 
    5515}, {16.2253, 5459}, {16.284, 5419}, {15.6112, 5389}, {15.7221,
     5403}, {15.509, 5445}, {15.6993, 5401}, {15.961, 5400}, {16.6001,
     5379}, {16.3766, 5411}, {16.4999, 5437}, {16.3784, 
    5483}, {16.9554, 5510}, {16.9463, 5482}, {17.2453, 
    5455}, {17.0854, 5476}, {16.9786, 5407}, {17.2081, 
    5425}, {17.4898, 5428}, {17.1521, 5457}, {17.8233, 5382}, {17.726,
     5448}, {17.7837, 5400}, {17.5088, 5398}, {17.8232, 
    5454}, {18.4418, 5385}};

 SmoothHistogram3D[data]
```

[image]

here is a "Log" scaling function. ( I could not get any kind of reasonable plot without manually specifying the plot range )

```
SmoothHistogram3D[data, ScalingFunctions -> {None, None, "Log"}, 
 PlotRange -> {-12, -5}
```

[image: ]]

if you want "-Log" you need to specify a custom function:

```
 SmoothHistogram3D[data, ScalingFunctions -> {None, None, -Log[#] &}, 
     PlotRange -> {5, 12}]
```

[image]

The failure of automatic plot range to work may be a bug.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but still one problem, when I use the -Log[#] & , I am getting the plot (I add it to my question above) which it does not make any sense for me, but when I use the LOG, the graph is exactly what it should be.

Comment: If you want to use log. `Histogram3D[data, ScalingFunctions -> {None, None, "Log"}]`

Answer (score 2):

```
data = {{16.3009, 5454}, {16.2118, 5463}, {15.8156, 5414}, {15.9585, 
    5515}, {16.2253, 5459}, {16.284, 5419}, {15.6112, 5389}, {15.7221, 
    5403}, {15.509, 5445}, {15.6993, 5401}, {15.961, 5400}, {16.6001, 
    5379}, {16.3766, 5411}, {16.4999, 5437}, {16.3784, 5483}, {16.9554, 
    5510}, {16.9463, 5482}, {17.2453, 5455}, {17.0854, 5476}, {16.9786, 
    5407}, {17.2081, 5425}, {17.4898, 5428}, {17.1521, 5457}, {17.8233, 
    5382}, {17.726, 5448}, {17.7837, 5400}, {17.5088, 5398}, {17.8232, 
    5454}, {18.4418, 5385}};
```

To get the ranges of the data

```
{xmin, xmax} = MinMax[data[[All, 1]]];

{ymin, ymax} = MinMax[data[[All, 2]]];

distr = SmoothKernelDistribution[data];
```

To plot the probability density function ([`PDF`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PDF.html)) of the distribution

```
skd = Plot3D[PDF[distr, {x, y}],
  {x, xmin, xmax}, {y, ymin, ymax},
  PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.7],
  ColorFunction -> ColorData["TemperatureMap"]]
```

[image]

To scale the Histogram3D as a PDF

```
Energy1 = Histogram3D[data, Automatic, "PDF",
  ColorFunction -> ColorData["TemperatureMap"],
  ChartStyle -> Opacity[0.7]]
```

[image]

```
Show[skd, Energy1]
```

[image]

The results should be better with the full data set.